# How to solve error in HTK ERROR [+2662] FindProtoModel: no proto for ei in hSet

Tags: speech-recognition, htk

I am running julius after changing the grammer and added few new sentences and in step 10 i am getting this error.

```
 AU fulllist
 Creating HMMset using trees to add unseen triphones
  ERROR [+2662]  FindProtoModel: no proto for ei in hSet
 FATAL ERROR - Terminating program C:\cygwin\HTK\htk-3.3-windows-binary\htk\HHEd.exe
```

How can i solve this or change the grammar what can I change? added fe sentenses already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that the HHEd tool fails to find the model for the phone 'ei' trained on the previous step. You need to make sure that this phone has enough training data from the step 1 or you can remove this phone from the phoneset, dictionary and all list altogether. If you are using Voxforge English acoustic model training tutorial, there should be no phone ei. Maybe you just need to remove it from your dictionary.

Comment: If I have to train HHED toool for this. How many mor examples do I need and is there a command to check whether my prompts file is phonetically correct before i run all the steps.? I read manual of julius which says it has but i cannot find it anywhere how to use it. I run the recognition by changing Jconf file so that it use only  Monophones to recognise.? Is it a good idea to do for a small sentence?  

I still lack "ar" "ix" phhones only which confuses me as i dont know how manny number of words should i use in my sample voice for each phone.??  if there is a number!

Comment: To train you need at least 100 examples of each phone in each context. Usually it's several hours of audio

Comment: Recognition with only monophones is a bad idea

Comment: The easiest way for you is to use another dictionary which phoneset matches the one from the acoustic model. Such dictionary should not contain phones like ar and ix.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this phoneme from the fulllist and run the HHEd again.